# Why don't root elements of stacking contexts stack if their properties differ?

Tags: css, z-index

I was very surprised today when an element with a `transform` that isn't `none` didn't stack above an element with a `position` that is `absolute` despite having a higher z-index. However, adding `position:absolute|relative` to the former element made z-index perform as expected between them.

Take a look: I expected in the following for the green square (with `transform:translateX(0)`) to stack above them all the others from having the highest `z-index`, but it only stacks above the blue square which precedes it in the DOM. I attribute it to the blue square having `z-index:0` and some degenerate behavior, as though both have `z-index:0`.

```css
div {
  opacity:0.8;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
body {
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:blue; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:0;">
</div>
<div style="background-color:green; transform:translateX(0); z-index:2;">
</div>
<div style="background-color:red; position:absolute; top:20px; left:20px; z-index:1;">
</div>
```

My expectation was that all of the elements above are in the root stacking context. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**z-index works on flex items and positioned elements**(an element is “positioned” means that it has a position value other than static, e.g., relative, absolute and fixed).
 If you try to set a `z-index` on an element with no position specified, it will do nothing.

So, just set `position` of `green div` to `relative/absolute/fixed`, it will be stack on top of all the div.

```css
div {
  opacity:0.8;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
body {
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:blue; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:0;">
</div>
<div style="background-color:green;position:relative; transform:translateX(0); z-index:2;">
</div>
<div style="background-color:red; position:absolute; top:20px; left:20px; z-index:1;">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I know `z-index` works for flex items as well but here poster confused with `position` in the OP. Anyways, my 1st point is not 100% correct so, updated it.